# How can i correctly assign a value to a private static variable in PHP class?

Tags: php

I have a class that translate language array base. So the problem is that the language does not change base on a cookie value.

this function should set the language value but it does not. it seems that no matter what i do i always get "ar" as a self::$currlang value. how can i correct this issue?

```
public function _set(){

    if( $_COOKIE['defaultLang'] != '' ) {
        self::$currlang = $_COOKIE['defaultLang'];
    } else {
        //this is the default language
        self::$currlang = 'ar';
    }

}
```

here is my code

thanks for your help :)

```
<?php
include('../langs/english.php');
include('../langs/arabic.php');

class Translator{
    private static $strs = array();
    private static $currlang = "";


    public function _set(){

        if( $_COOKIE['defaultLang'] != '' ) {
            self::$currlang = $_COOKIE['defaultLang'];
        } else {
            //this is the default language
            self::$currlang = 'ar';
        }

    }


    public static function loadTranslation($lang, $strs){
        if (empty(self::$strs[$lang]))
            self::$strs[$lang] = array();

        self::$strs[$lang] = array_merge(self::$strs[$lang], $strs);        
    }

    public static function setDefaultLang($lang){
        self::$currlang = $lang;        
    }

     public static function getDefaultLang(){
        return self::$currlang;        
    }

    public static function translate($key, $lang=""){
        if ($lang == ""){
            $lang = self::$currlang;
        }
        $str = self::$strs[$lang][$key];
        if (empty($str)){
            //$str = "$lang.$key"; 
            $str = 'Language "'. $lang . '", '. $key . ' is not defined.';           
        } 
        return $str;       
    }    

    public static function freeUnused(){
        foreach(self::$strs as $lang => $data){
            if ($lang != self::$currlang){
                $lstr = self::$strs[$lang]['langname'];
                self::$strs[$lang] = array();
                self::$strs[$lang]['langname'] = $lstr;                
            }            
        }        
    }

    public static function getLangList(){
        $list = array();
        foreach(self::$strs as $lang => $data){
            $h['name'] = $lang;
            $h['desc'] = self::$strs[$lang]['langname'];
            $h['current'] = $lang == self::$currlang;
            $list[] = $h;
        }
        return $list;        
    }

    public static function &getAllStrings($lang){
        return self::$strs[$lang];
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: why is the current language a STATIC attribute of your class?!  what's the point of a translator class if they all share the same language?

Comment: I dont't see a problem in your code. Provide a usage sample and the value, the static variable has, once the code finished.

Comment: @mike Additionally, why do you implement a magic setter _set() - without evaluating the name of the variable to be set. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

Comment: I have converted all self:: to $this-> and also removed static. But I now get a new error "Using $this when not in object context in this code line 2"
    public function loadTranslation($lang, $strs){
        if ( empty($this->$strs[$lang]) ){
            $this->$strs[$lang] = array();
  }
        $this->$strs[$lang] = array_merge($this->$strs[$lang], $strs);        
    }

current code
    private $strs = array();
    public $currlang;

 public function _set(){
  if( $_COOKIE['defaultLang'] != '' ) {
   $this->$currlang = $_COOKIE['defaultLang'];
  } else {
   $this->$currlang = 'ar';
  }
 }

Answer (score 1):

The _set() magic method works with the -> operator, which works with instantiated objects.  You can't use static member variables with instantiated objects, it's one or the other.

Comment: So what should I change set to? How can I set those variables base on the cookies?

Comment: I would create a set( $varname, 'value' ) method that is static, that basically has the same internal code that you currently have =)  Then you'd call it with $obj::set('name','value)

Comment: jhansen this would work when i change the language but i want the language to be automatically detected if the cookies is set. so i set the cookies of a drop down menu change and when ever the translator class is included then it should set the language base of the cookie value

Comment: Jhansen, I did what you said and I called that method where I included the class and it worked :).  Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help, don't forget to up vote and select me as the solution! =D